# Elegant way to find mutually exclusive tuples in the list based on the element present in each tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples, operators, subtraction

I want to subtract the two following tuples from each other to get the desired result (also included below). Note that the subtraction is based on only the a of the (a, b).

```
# the two tuples
first = [(('the',), 431), (('and',), 367)]
second = [(('the',), 100), (('hello',), 100)]

# the desired result
first = [(('and',), 367)]
second = [(('hello',), 100)]
```

I tried `map(operation.sub, first, second)`, didn't work. Tried `b = map(sub, first, second)`, didn't work. Says **unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'tuple**.

Thanks for your help and time in advance.

**Edit**: A solution that would help me most would include creating an intersection of the two tuples and subtracting that from each of the tuples.

Edit: I want to subtract based on common items. Hope that clarifies it.

Comment: the desired result is unclear

Comment: your desire is unclear; to get your result literally, you can use: `first = first[1]` or `first = list(first[1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe follow is what you want：

```
# the two tuples
first = [(('the',), 431), (('and',), 367)]
second = [(('the',), 100), (('hello',), 100)]

first_keys = set(_[0][0] for _ in first)
second_keys = set(_[0][0] for _ in second)

first = [_ for _ in first if _[0][0] not in second_keys]
second = [_ for _ in second if _[0][0] not in first_keys]
```

---

```
multi = [
    [(('the',), 431), (('and',), 367)],
    [(('the',), 100), (('hello',), 100)]
]

def get_key(x):
    return x[0][0]

def occur_counts(set_x):
    cnt = {}
    for x in set_x:
        cnt[get_key(x)] = cnt.get(get_key(x), 0) + 1
    return cnt


def do_one(single, total_cnt):
    single_cnt = occur_counts(single)
    return [_ for _ in single if single_cnt[get_key(_)] == total_cnt[get_key(_)]]


total_cnt = occur_counts(sum(multi, []))

answer = [do_one(_, total_cnt) for _ in multi]
```

Comment: I tried this, but it gave me the same two sets/tuples back.

Comment: use 'first = [_ for _ in first if _[0][0] not in second_keys]' instead of first = [_ for _ in first if _[0][0] not in second] . sorry for my  carelessness

Comment: Works, great, thanks. can you tell me how I go about automating this for more than 2 tuples? I could do it by hand for each two, but would be good to automate it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you are looking for -

```
# the two tuples
first = [(('the',), 431), (('and',), 367)]
second = [(('the',), 100), (('hello',), 100)]

interim1 = {i[0][0]:i[1] for i in first}

interim2 = {i[0][0]:i[1] for i in second}

op1 = [ ((item,),interim1[item]) for item in interim1 if item not in interim2]
op2 = [ ((item,),interim2[item]) for item in interim2 if item not in interim1]
print(op1)
print(op2)
```

**Intersection (Edit)**

```
intersection = [ ((item,),interim1[item]) for item in interim1 if item in interim2]
print(intersection)
```

**Union (Extra)**

```
union = set().union(*[ op1, op2, intersection])
print(union)
```

**Output**

```
[(('the',), 431)]
[(('and',), 367)]
[(('hello',), 100)]
{(('hello',), 100), (('and',), 367), (('the',), 431)}
```

Comment: How do you take the intersection of more than two sets/tuples/lists?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`set`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) with below *list comprehension* to get the desired result as:

```
>>> first = [(('the',), 431), (('and',), 367)]
>>> second = [(('the',), 100), (('hello',), 100)]

>>> [t for t in first+second if t[0] in set(f[0] for f in first) ^ (set(s[0] for s in second))]
[(('and',), 367), (('hello',), 100)]
```

---

**Explanation:**

Here, I am using set to get the non-common words in the two list by performing [*XOR (also know as Exclusive OR)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) on two sets. For example:

```
>>> first_words = set(f[0] for f in first)
>>> second_words = set(s[0] for s in second)

>>> first_words ^ second_words
set([('hello',), ('and',)])
```

Then I am iterating on both the list within *list comprehension* and checking whether they are present in above set of *non-common* words tuples. If they are present, then we are keeping it as the part of new list as:

```
>>> result = [t for t in first+second if t[0] in first_words ^ second_words]
# where `result` will hold value `[(('and',), 367), (('hello',), 100)]`

## If your resultant lists contains only two variable, 
## then you may assign them directly to individual variable as:
#     f, s = [t for t in first+second if t[0] in first_words ^ second_words]

## where `f` first required tuple will hold
# >>> f
# (('and',), 367)

## and `s` second required tuple will hold
# >>> s
# (('hello',), 100)
```

Comment: Thanks. The more detailed version doesn't work for me, as it gives me this error: 'too many values to unpack' for this line f, s = [t for t in first+second if t[0] in first_words ^ second_words]. The first code you wrote works fine, but gives me the same result both ways around.

Comment: Are you using different list then the one mentioned in the example? The error you are seeing in because `f, s = <my code` assumes two values in the returned tuple assigns the values to `f` and `s`. Check the edit.

Comment: No, there are numerous value pairs of this kind: ('hello'), 100 in the tuples.

Comment: check the updated version.. it will contain the list of tuples as `result`. You may access them with `result[0]`, `result[1]`, .... so on

Comment: Works well now, thank you. Any idea how I can select multiple answers to my question? All three provided different, but valid answers.

Comment: You need not to worry about that. You can just select one answer, and always while accepting the answer, make sure to select the one which you think is the most elegant way to achieve the result, as it acts as a reference for the future readers regarding what they should use. However, you may up-vote multiple answers which you see are good by clicking on the grey arrow pointing upwards at the left of each answer